# How to send form information to email address

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm new in vb.net can please tell me how can i send the content of any form to specify email address on submit button. For example if anyone fill the contact form the on submission all the form data will be send to particular email address which we can specify in coding.
Please define me step by step because I'm little bit weak in coding.

Comment: Please add a `winforms` or `asp.net` tag (or any other that applies).

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this short and sweet tutorial](http://mikesdotnetting.com/Article/41/Send-form-content-by-email-in-ASP.NET).

Comment: or the sample in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx